# Global Inbox shown to not logged in users?

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

I don't know about you, but should the Global inbox be shown to users who aren't logged in/new?

[image]

Seems a little confusing for annonymous to have an inbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed sometime ago.

You'll only see the inbox tab if logged in now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it still works (answers to their questions and whatnot are shown in the inbox), then I see no reason to get rid of it. If not, then obviously it's useless

Comment: How can it know answers to show if they aren't logged in?

Comment: @Grace Well, you can still post if you're not logged in. I guess it could be hidden until after you've posted, but my point was it should be possible to get alerts despite not having a registered account, so showing it just to registered users is probably wrong

Comment: @Michael If you don't have a registered account, you have a cookie. With the cookie, you're considered logged in, even if still unregistered. So it can easily grab your credentials if you aren't registered and thus your inbox, but that's irrelevant to people who aren't even logged in at all.

Comment: @Grace I guess I'm unclear about the original question then; he refers to "users who aren't logged in/new" and "anonymous" users. Anonymous/new/unregistered/whatever-you-want-to-call-them users should have the inbox. Users who aren't logged in probably shouldn't, although I'm unclear where the line between those is (I suppose when you first post you switch from being logged out to being unregistered but technically logged in)

Comment: Ah, I missed that. New users and not-logged-in users are completely different beasts, so I'm not sure why they're being grouped. I agree with you, new users should be allowed an inbox (I imagine they are), but not-logged-in users really have nothing to show for it.

Comment: @Grace @Michael Is this currently implemented for new users or is it just a "maybe" feature? Because if its not, then the inbox is confusing and unusable and should be removed. Then once the feature is done it can be reshown